# User can't view document version history

Tags: 2007, document-library, version-history

The situation in brief:

- The site is hosted on a MOSS 2007 server.
- All contents of the site inherit permissions.
- A document library with versioning enabled is on the site.
- A group has been created to grant 'Full Control'.
- 4 users have been added to this group.
- 3 of the users in the group can view document version history.
- **1 user can not see the document history**, nothing happens when clicking the link.

After some testing it has been found this particular user:

- can not change the site (although could update documents).
- can not view his 'My Settings' from the welcome drop-down.
- this behavior persists after having him launch a browser with 'Run as...', making sure domain credentials are used.
- has the **same behavior on a test site** I created on a seperate WSS 3.0 server on which I add him with explicit 'Full Control'.

What, other than 'Full Control', is required to view version history?  And perhaps more to the point, what can prevent it?

--edit--

From all indications the users is logged onto the network using his domain account (email, domain shares and so on work fine).  The permissions are for the domain account.

Comment: Any way to verify what account he is using? Most of the time we experience something weird like this, a user is logging in with an account different than the one with permissions.

Comment: I had him launch the browser with 'Run as...' to make sure he was using domain credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 user can not see the document history, **nothing happens when clicking the link**

I guess that this is a client problem rather than a user account/ permission error. Can you check if the user is able to do all these things on another machine?

If I understand correctly there is no "Acccess denied" message -right? So that might be client / browser / security setting issue. Sounds like maybe some JavaScipt isn't running on that machine.

It is very vage, but you might give it a chance.

Comment: I have had the user visit a page with a simple script to display a message stating if JavaScript is enabled or not -- it is.

Comment: Yes, the version history link does nothing -- no error screen or such.

Comment: I would recommend a quick cross check if possible: So, user A on machine B; and user B on machine A. That should give us a hint if it is user related or machine related.

Comment: finally got word back from the user.  He was able to log in from a different machine fine.  I turned the problem over to our PC-support department to straighten out his client settings.  Most likely some browser settings that aren't standard.